# What is an equivalent version of maple software in linux?

Tags: math-software, maple

> What is an equivalent version of maple software in linux?

From the comment by james, I am editing this post.

Maple is not a free version as i have searched in google. I need equivalent versions..

### About me

I am using Linux mint for my operating system.. Only for this software I dont want to go to windows..

> I know for SPSS in windows I am having GNU PSPP is equivalent..

Like that what is the equivalent version for maple in Linux..

I am having Free mat in my os. Is it an equivalent version of Maple??

Comment: Maple is available on Linux.

Comment: There is a free CAS called Sage that works on Linux. It is quite different from Maple, so I wouldn't call it equivalent. You can't run your Maple code in it, as far as I am aware. But it is quite comprehensive in its own right, and seems to be popular.

Comment: Focus on what kind of computations you want to do, and whether you need a graphical interface, etc. FreeMat will not provide the general advanced math that a Computer Algebra System like Maple does. But if you actually want mostly scientific and engineering applications then consider Scilab before FreeMat, as it's functionality is broader and more recently developed. Sage can get you more of the advanced math than does FreeMat (and interface with your Scilab too). Take a look at this comparison: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_numerical_analysis_software